# Can we write nested if else condition for performing the operation over the content of CSV files in ApacheNifi?

Tags: apache-nifi

Can we write generic Expression language for the below code snippet in Nifi using processors?
Let's say I have 2 csv files.
One csv file has columns: X, Y1, Y2, Z
Other csv file has columns: X, Y3, Y4, Z
Output file should have columns: X, Y, Z

where Y= Y1+Y2 in first case.
Y = Y3+Y4 in second case.

How do we check in Nifi for if else condition, as in if y1, y2 are present then concatenate and form Y. If Y3, Y4 are present then concatenate and form Y.

The code snippet for it looks something like this to populate values of column Y -

```
If (Y == empty) 
{
        If (Y1 != empty and Y2 != empty) 
        {
                Y = concat(Y1, Y2)
        }
        else if (Y4 != empty and Y5 != empty)
        {
                Y = concat(Y4, Y5)
        }
}
```

Comment: Nifi Expression Language does allow nested ifElse statements.BUT, you haven't provide us with logic how are ou going to join that two CSV files into a single one?

Comment: So, there are 2 input files, there will be 2 output files with same schema.
suppose 1st input file has columns SSN,F_Name,L_Name.
Second input file has columns: SocialSecurity,FirstName,LastName.
2 output files will have columns Social_Security, First_Name, Last_Name.

Comment: in Nifi it's easy to apply transformations within the same file, or split the file. If the you need to join files - than the things get little bit more complex, and there are a lot of IF there. Could you provide an example of input_file_1.csv, input_file_2.csv, and expected_output.csv? Also is that possible that you will have 3 files of type 1 and 2 files of type 2 (not one-to-one correlation). And how are you going to assosiate the rows between to files. Unfortunatelly, you question doesn't provide the enough level of details to be answered